# Apply keyframe in Material UI v4 | react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to apply a pulse effect to an icon in Material UI v4,
but for some reason, it's not working

```
    `const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    '@keyframes ripple': {
        '0%': {
            boxShadow: `0 0 0 0rem rgba($ripple-color, 0.2),
            0 0 0 1rem rgba($ripple-color, 0.2),
            0 0 0 2rem rgba($ripple-color, 0.2),
            0 0 0 5rem rgba($ripple-color, 0.2)`,
        },
        '100%': {
            boxShadow: `0 0 0 1rem rgba($rippleC-color, 0.2),
            0 0 0 2rem rgba($ripple-color, 0.2),
            0 0 0 5rem rgba($ripple-color, 0.2),
            0 0 0 8rem rgba($ripple-color, 0)`,
        },

    dot: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize: '3.5rem',
        backgroundColor: '#2E2E2E',
        borderRadius: '50px',
        animation: '$ripple 2s linear infinite',
    },

}));
```

const func = () => {
return <BlurOnIcon className={classes.dot} style={{ color: '#90EE90', animationDelay: '0s' }} />;
};`

Comment: Is `.dot` or `#dot` instead of `dot` working?

Comment: `.dot` show an error, `#dot` doesn't make any change

Comment: How about '.dot' ?

Comment: not working either